# Email not going out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to generate Email from my ruby application, So i used Action mail class for that.

I configured the Email setting on environment.rb  my configuration is as follows

```
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = false
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "mail.authsmtp.com",
    :port => 2525,
    :user_name => "*******",
    :password => "*******",
    :authentication => :login
}
```

My mailer model is TestMailer,so i decided to check the mail operation so define method on TestMailer.rb.

```
def  test_mail(to) {
    subject "My first email!"
    recipients "#{to}"
    from 'test'
    charset "utf-8"
    content_type 'text/html'
    body "Testing one two three..."
}
```

I opened the ruby  Script/console and called the test_mail method by `TestMailer.deliver_test_mail("example@gmail.com")`.

It is not generating the email. In the application server log its generates the email template.
I have no clue whats is the probs here .

Comment: What does `ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries` give you in console? Does your log state that the email was delivered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check config/environments/development.rb | test.rb | production.rb 
(depending on how you launched you console)

And verify if it does not overrides the smtp setting you have in environment.rb

Answer (score 0):

If you ran this:

```
ruby script/console
```

... then you're in development mode, which probably has "perform_deliveries = false" or some other setting for **delivery_method**

Instead, run the console in production mode:

```
ruby script/console production
```

... or change config/environments/development.rb to "perform_deliveries = true".

Note this comment from environment.rb:

```
# Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
```

So, if something is defined in both places, it'll be overridden by the environment specific setting!